# android, hide actionbar Tab, but keep the tab functionality

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have tabs in my webview, and I want to map the each tab in the webview to android tab. (I have done this already, except I now have 2 tab-views, 1 android tab, 1 webview tab)

Webview's tab is hidden when user scroll down and shown when user scroll up, and I don't know how to do that with android tabs.
(I don't know if it's possible)

Hiding the android tab will work perfectly for me.
But `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)` disables tab functionality. (e.g. `setSelectedNavigationItem()` doesn't work when in `STANDARD` mode)

Can I somehow hide the tab but keep the tab functionality at the same time?

Comment: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and likely will remain deprecated in the next Android release. You may wish to consider switching to another tab implementation (e.g., `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, `FragmentTabHost`).

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for input. Would it be possible to visually hide the tab with FragmentTabHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be possible to visually hide the tab with FragmentTabHost?

The actual "tabs" for `FragmentTabHost` are provided by a `TabWidget`. The biggest problem with `TabHost`/`FragmentTabHost` for your scenario is that the `TabWidget` needs to be a child of the `TabHost`/`FragmentTabHost`. If your `minSdkVersion` is 14 or higher, you should be able to use the new animator APIs to achieve your desired effect, but I am uncertain if you can pull off what you want with the old animation APIs.